# Как убрать выделение при наведении курсора?

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Как убрать выделение окна при наведении курсора

```
fun main() = application {
    val windowState = rememberWindowState(
        position = WindowPosition(x = 100.dp, y = 100.dp)
    )
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        state = windowState,
        undecorated = true
    ) {
       WindowDraggableArea(
           modifier = Modifier
               .clickable {
                   setPosition(
                       windowState.position.y.value.toInt(),
                       windowState.position.x.value.toInt()
                   )
               }
       ){
           Text(
               " Text(\"Window position: ${windowState.position}\")",
               fontSize = 24.sp,
               modifier =  Modifier.fillMaxSize()

           )
       }
    }
}

fun setPosition(top: Int, left: Int) {
    val fileName = "data.json"
    val file = File(fileName)
    val json = Json.encodeToString(WindowPosition(top = top, left = left))
    file.writeText(json)
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно убрать только эффект при наведении курсора или в том числе ripple-эффект по нажатию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы убрать все эффекты, связанные с кликом, передайте параметр `indication` со значением `null`. Для этого необходимо также передать параметр `interactionSource`:

```
Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = null
) {
    // действие по клику
}
```